# How to let a text blink and change color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I programmed an alarm clock as my first Web-project. Now I want, that my RemainingTime "clock" starts blinking and changing color after every 15 minutes for 1 minute.
I found some code in the internet but that doesnt work for me :/
I started the funktion blinking() with checking if the minutes/15 is an integer value.
Thanks for helping me :)

```
function blinking()
{
    remainingMinutes = Math.floor(pDateTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 60000;
    remainingMinutesf = Math.ceil(remainingMinutes % 60).toString().padStart(2, "0");
    console.log(remainingMinutesf);

    if(Number.isInteger(remainingMinutesf/15))
    {
        var BlinkingClock = document.getElementById("Remainclock");
        setInterval(function()
        {
            
        },1000)

    }

}
```

```
#RemainClock {
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    font-size: 5vw;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,
        rgba(99,253,136,1) 0%,
        rgba(51,197,142,1) 50%,
        rgba(39,97,116,1) 100%);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: This question will probably be closed. For future, I will advise to narrow down your problem to pin point which part of your code is not working. To be honest, no one will go line by line in your code and assume what may be wrong.

Comment: Well theres is nothing wrong with this code, it is working 100%.
But i will shorten the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function blinking()
{
    var BlinkingClock = document.getElementById("RemainClock");
    BlinkingClock.style.color = "red";
    BlinkingClock.style.visibility = (BlinkingClock.style.visibility == "hidden" ? "" : "hidden");


}
```